# Add CustomAttribute to catalog/product collection

Tags: magento-1.9

In Catalog/product/list i have some collection like this :

```
$_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

and `foreach ($_productCollection as $_product)`
I want to do some condition in products with some attribute that i have added in admin
in `$_product->getData();` i dont find my attribute

if i do my collection i find it:

```
<?php $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('promo', 1)
    ->setPageSize(10);
?>
<?php foreach($collection as $col): ?>
    <?php echo $col->getSku(); ?><br/> // 123
    <?php echo $col->getPromo(); ?> //1
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: make sure you have assigned that attribute to respective attribute set

Comment: that is to say ? i have created it in admin panel catalog/manage products i clicked in any product then in general add a new attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Solution is :

**1) The bad one:**

```
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) {
  $loadProd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
  $customAttribute = $loadProd->getPromo();
}
```

**2) The good one:**

1. We should set the attribute to `Use in Product Listing` to yes in admin.
2. After adding the attribute, we should **reindexAll**.
3. Clear the browser and Magento cache.
4. Now we will find our **promo** attribute in the collection.

Comment: This may work, but it is very inefficient. You should use Amit's suggestion.

Comment: Yes i know, look my update @thedash

Answer (score 0):

In this case,you can  need some code.

- First,enable  attribute ,**promo** for **Use in Product Listing**
  From
  *Admin -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes* select attribute and

And add `->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())` to **collection**

Comment: Where i add the ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes()) ?

Comment: in place of ` ->addAttributeToFilter('promo', 1)`

Comment: you have't understand my question, i wont to do somthing in $_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection(); to have my custom attribute in this collection or in the getData()